# How to aggregate in Camel using the Akka 1.3 integration?

Tags: apache-camel, akka

The Akka integration is super nice, but I cannot seem to find any examples on how to aggregate using the Producer actors. My producer is super simple:

```
    class BindingCandidateProducer(config: Configuration)
            extends Actor
            with Producer
            with Oneway
            with Logging
            with Instrumented {

        import BindingCandidateJsonProtocol._

        def endpointUri = "file:data/bindings?fileName=bindings.${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmm}.mjson"

        override protected def receiveBeforeProduce = {
            case bindingCandidate: BindingCandidate => bindingCandidate.toJson.compactPrint
        }
    }
```

NOTE: *mjson* is the internal name for "multi json", a file format where each line is a complete JSON message.

I'm trying to aggregate multiple BindingCandidate objects into a single file. How and where do I specify my aggregator? Is it a separate actor that lives before this one? There is no information about aggregators on the [Akka 1.3 Camel documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-modules/1.3.1/modules/camel.html). The Akka 2 documentation has no reference to Camel, although the code's still there. The Akka forum has a single thread about [camel aggregation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/akka-user/camel%2420aggregation).

I'm still on Akka 1.3, Scala 2.9, but using Camel 2.12.2.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but I think I found the solution: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-modules/1.3.1/modules/camel.html#Custom_Camel_route_example shows how to use a custom route builder. The builder is based on Apache Camel's builder, which enables use of everything, including aggregation.

Comment: Btw here is the camel documentation for Akka 2: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/camel.html